# Federal Register XMLHttpRequest | What am I doing wrong?

Tags: xml, get, xmlhttprequest

I have an XML file provided by the Federal Register that Im trying to place on my website using an
`XMLHttpRequest` GET request.

https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/full_text/xml/2023/04/03/2023-06310.xml

I have the following script

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("fed-reg-29").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/full_text/xml/2023/04/03/2023-06310.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I know the script works because I use it with other XML files.

This XML file, however, does not work with my script. I have tried it multiple times with no success.

I have also tried my preferred method as follows

```
<div>
<b>Agency:</b> <span id="SUBAGY"></span><br>
<b>Action:</b> <span id="ACT"></span><br>
<b>Summary:</b> <span id="SUM"></span>
</div>

<script>
var xmlhttp, xmlDoc;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "view-source:https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/full_text/xml/2023/04/03/2023-06310.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
document.getElementById("SUBAGY").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SUBAGY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("ACT").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ACT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("SUM").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SUM")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>
```

Still doesn't work. What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!